# Semimartingale characteristics for stochastic integral?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I'm recently reading Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes. A question came to my mind when going through the theory of Characteristics of Semimartingales in Ch. 2. How to figure out the **characteristics for a general stochastic integral**? To be specific,

> Let $X$ be a $d$-dimensional semimartingale, with characteristics $(B,C,\nu)$ relative to a truncation function $h$, $H$ be a locally bounded predictable
>   processes. Then it's well-known that, the stochastic integral $H\cdot X=\int_0^\cdot H_s dX_s$ is a semimartingale. The question is, what the characteristics of $H\cdot X$ look like?

I cannot find it out within this book. Could anyone give some reference or comments? Appreciate!

Comment: It's in the book, exact reference would be Proposition 5.3 of Chapter IX section "5a Characteristics of Stochastic Integrals" Regards

Comment: @TheBridge That's really good, I did't see it before. But I gotta question for Prop. IX.5.3. Why does it concern on the characteristics for the $(d+m)$-dimensional semimartingale $Z:=(X,H\cdot X)$ instead of that for $H\cdot X$? How can we get the latter from the former?

Comment: In formula 5.2 its the term of the second line for $B'^i$,i.e. i>d i what you want, for $C'^{i,j} $ the formula of the third line i.e. with  i and  j>d, it is. And as for v' you have to restrict the formula in the same way getting an expression like 1_G * v' = 1_G (Hx) * v. unless mistaken

Comment: @TheBridge I got the idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post an answer of myself here. Denote $Y=H\cdot X$, and the characteristics of $Y$ by $(B'',C'',\nu'')$.

If we want to find out the characteristics of $Y$, we'd better make an assumption for the integrand $H$:

> **Assumption** The $d\times d$ matrix-valued process $H$ is a.s. nondegenerate, that is,
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathbf P\{\text{det}(H_t)\ne0, \forall t\ge0\}=1.
> \end{equation}

The assumption is to insure that 
\begin{equation}\tag{*}
\Delta Y\ne0 \quad\text{if and only if}\quad \Delta X \ne0,
\end{equation}
since $\Delta Y=H\Delta X$. One may make other assumptions to insure it. Thus if $\mu^X$ and $\mu^Y$ denote the random measures associated with the jumps of $X$ and $Y$, then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mu^Y (dt,dy) & = \sum_s\mathbf 1_{\{\Delta Y_s\ne 0\}} \delta_{(s,\Delta Y_s)}(dt,dy) \\
& = \sum_s\mathbf 1_{\{\Delta X_s\ne 0\}} \delta_{(s,H_s\Delta X_s)}(dt,dy).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Thus, for any $G\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R_+)\otimes\mathcal  B(\mathbb R^d)$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(\mathbf 1_G*\mu^Y)_t & = \mu^Y(([0,t]\times\mathbb R^d)\cap G) \\
& = \sum_s\mathbf 1_{\{\Delta X_s\ne 0\}} \delta_{(s,H_s\Delta X_s)}(([0,t]\times\mathbb R^d)\cap G)\\
& = \sum_s\mathbf 1_{\{\Delta X_s\ne 0\}} \delta_{(s,\Delta X_s)}(([0,t]\times\mathbb R^d)\cap\{(r,x):(r,H_r x))\in G\})\\
& = \int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathbf 1_G(r,H_r x))\mu^X(dr,dx).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Once we get this, all the rest of procedure are the same as the proof of Proposition IX.5.3 in the book "Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes". Finally, we obtain the characteristics
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
B''&=\{B'_i;d+1\le i\le d+m\} = H\cdot B + (h'(Hx)-Hh(x))*\nu, \\
C''&=\{C'_{ij};d+1\le i\le d+m,d+1\le j\le d+m\} = \{(H^k_i H^l_j)\cdot C_{kl}\}, \\
(\mathbf 1_G*\nu'')_t & =\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathbf 1_G(r,H_r x))\nu(dr,dx).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

**Remark** In fact, the condition (*) can be weakened to that
\begin{equation}\tag{**}
\Delta Y\ne0 \Rightarrow \Delta X \ne0,
\end{equation}
and the conclusion still holds. That is, the Assumption is not necessary at all.